# agrid problem using filter with afterViewInit

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I got a problemusing AgGrid.

When i create a component :

If the component implement OnInit (the data is passed by rowData) the agGrid is empty and i can't filter anything.

If i implement AfterViewIinit the data are show as the datagrid is updated with the method :

```
this.grid.api.setDatasource({
      getRows: (params) => {
        params.successCallback(this.grid.rowData, this.companyfiles.length)
      }
    })
```

but using this, when i use the filter from agGrid, i think the getRows method is not updated.

here is the sample from the ts page :

```
import { AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { FileVisualizationV2 } from "@libs/file/api/models/file-visualisation-v2";
import { IDatasource, ModelUpdatedEvent } from "ag-grid-community";
import { TranslationService } from '@libs/i18n/services/translation.service';
import { justifyRightCol, justifyCenterCol, justifyLeftCol, checkboxSelectionColumn } from '@libs/ag-grid/column-types';
import { AgGridAngular } from "ag-grid-angular";

@Component({
  selector: 'file-management-list-details-v2',
  templateUrl: './file-management-list-details-v2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-management-list-details-v2.component.scss'],
})

export class FileManagementListDetailsComponentV2 implements OnInit, AfterViewInit
{


  @Input() set companyfilesData(value: FileVisualizationV2[]){
    this.companyfiles = value;
  };
  public companyfiles : FileVisualizationV2[];
  @Output() fileAction = new EventEmitter<FileVisualizationV2>();

  @ViewChild(AgGridAngular) grid: AgGridAngular;
  public agGridTranslations$ = this.i18n.getTranslationSectionWhenReady('agGrid');

  constructor(private i18n: TranslationService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log( 'company files')
    console.log( this.companyfiles)
    console.log( 'after company files')
    console.log( 'company rowdata')
    console.log(this.grid.rowData)
      this.grid.api.setDatasource({
        rowCount: null,
        getRows: (params) => {
          params.successCallback(this.companyfiles, this.companyfiles.length)
        }
      } as IDatasource);
  }
  public columnTypes: any = {
    checkboxSelectionColumn,
    justifyCenterCol,
    justifyRightCol,
    justifyLeftCol,
    tinyCol: {
      minWidth: 70,
      maxWidth: 70
    },
    XSmallCol: {
      minWidth: 75,
      maxWidth: 75
    },
    smallCol: {
      minWidth: 85,
      maxWidth: 85
    },
    midCol: {
      minWidth: 100,
      maxWidth: 120
    },
    largeCol: {
      minWidth: 115,
      mawWidth: 150
    }
  };

   public columnDefs = [
    { headerName: this.i18n.translate('FileName'), field: 'fileName', type: ['justifyCenterCol'], resizable : true, filter: true, sortable: true,
    suppressMovable: true, editable: false, filterParams: {
      buttons: ['reset', 'apply']
  }},
  //   { headerName: ('OD'), cellRendererFramework: ButtonRendererComponent,
  // cellRendererParams: this.actionCellOnDemand, type: ['justifyCenterCol', 'iconCol'], resizable : true},
    { headerName: this.i18n.translate('uploadDate'), field: 'uploadDate', type: ['justifyCenterCol'] , resizable : true},
    { headerName: this.i18n.translate('uploadTime'), field: 'uploadTime', type: ['justifyCenterCol'] , resizable : true, filter: 'agDateColumnFilter'},
    { headerName: this.i18n.translate('currentOperation'), field: 'currentOperation', type: ['justifyCenterCol'] , resizable : true},
    { headerName: this.i18n.translate('numberOfRecords'), field: 'numberOfRecords', type: ['justifyCenterCol'] , resizable : true},
    { headerName: this.i18n.translate('uploadingUser'), field: 'uploadingUser', type: ['justifyCenterCol'] , resizable : true},
    { headerName: this.i18n.translate('ProgressPercentage'), field: 'progressPercentage', type: ['justifyCenterCol'] , resizable : true},
    // {
    //   headerName: this.i18n.translate('Actions'), cellRendererFramework: ButtonRendererComponent,
    //   cellRendererParams: this.actionCellRenderParams, minWidth : 300
    // }
  ];

  public onGridModelUpdated(event: ModelUpdatedEvent): void {
    event.api.sizeColumnsToFit();

     const brokerFilter = event.api.getFilterModel();
    this.grid.rowData = this.companyfiles.filter(x => x.fileName.includes('Joe'))
    this.grid.api.setDatasource({
      getRows: (params) => {
        params.successCallback(this.grid.rowData, this.companyfiles.length)
      }
    })
  }


  private updateDataSource(): void {

    if (this.grid && this.companyfiles != null && this.companyfiles.length > 0) {
      this.grid.api.setDatasource({
        rowCount: null,
        getRows: (params) => {
          params.successCallback(this.grid.rowData, this.companyfiles.length)
        }
      } as IDatasource);
    }
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.updateDataSource();
  }

}
```

does any one know how to filter ?

try using the data pass from datarow

using oninit to get the data